# Authorization and Authentication with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I have a web service that I have built on top of Spring. I am currently authenticating using Spring Security as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
@EnableWebSecurity

public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    private static final String ALL_URI = "/v1/**";
    private static final String HEALTH_URI = "/v1/healthCheck";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(getFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HEALTH_URI).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    private AuthenticationFilter getFilter() {
        return new AuthenticationFilter( properties.getKey());
    }
}
```

My `AuthenticationFilter` class extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and performs the actual authentication. If I want to add Authorization to my security, would I just make those checks in the `attemptAuthentication` method apart of the AuthenticationFilter? Or is there a better way to do it? The way I understand it is that Authorization and Authentication should be done independently. You first authenticate, and then you verify the permissions. So, I would assume there would be a better approach to do authorization within Spring Security rather than just adding it to the `attemptAuthentication` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `AuthenticationProvider` to do authenticate, implement the `AuthenticationProvider` and override the `authentication` and `supports` methods, and then inject to the `AuthenticationManager`.

`attemptAuthentication` method in filter is usually to get `authentication`(e.g. `UsernamePasswordFilter` gets `username` and `password` from request, and then builds a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to `AuthenticationManager` ),

`supports` method  tests the `AuthenticationProvider` whether can be used to do authenticate.(e.g `DaoAuthenticationProvider` supports `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`)

`authenticate` method is used to do authenticate(e.g `DaoAuthenticationProvider` gets the real password by username and then compare to the user input), this method should return an `Authentication` that is already authenticated(e.g `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`), and this authentication should contains the user authorities(this can be used to `hasRole('xxx')`), or use detail and so on.

After `attemptAuthentication` successful, the  `Authentication` will set into `SecurityContextHolder`. and then you can use the `hasRole('xx')`,  or something else.